# Merging two std::set's and (not yet) std::set::merge()

Tags: c++, std, c++17

I just wrote this code:

```
// Somewhere earlier, the equivalent of this happens.
std::set<T> a;
std::set<T> b;
FillMeUp(a);
FillMeUp(b);

// Later, in another function that sees a and b, this happens.
std::set<T> c;
std::set_union(a.begin(), a.end(),
               b.begin(), b.end(),
               std::inserter(c, c.begin()));
a.swap(c);
```

The point is that the second bit of code, under certain circumstances, wants to merge `a` and `b` together into `a`.

(For motivation: I have an array of objects with sets.  I iterate over that array.  If a certain condition is met, the object I am looking at essentially duplicates the object I saw just before, so I'd like to merge its set into the set just before.)

There's a new function in C++17 called [`std::set::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge), but my g++ 5.3.1 apparently doesn't know about it (says g++ 5.3.1 invoked with -std=c++17).

The question, really, is could I do better than what I've done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, `std::set::merge` is defined in the [draft standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/containers):

> Attempts to extract each element in a2 and insert it into a using the
>   comparison object of a. In containers with unique keys, if there is an
>   element in a with key equivalent to the key of an element from a2,
>   then that element is not extracted from a2.

With a complexity of:

> N log(a.size()+ N) where N has the value a2.size().

Since this matches the complexity of one of the overloads of `insert`:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

It sounds like a glorified wrapper of `insert`:

```
a.insert(b.begin(), b.end());
```

Comment: It's far from "a glorified wrapper of `insert`".

Comment: I agree, and it's also clearer than what I wrote.  I think the only thing that insert in this context doesn't do that merge would have done is that insert will copy where merge (iiuc) does moves, assuming that the second container's contents are no longer valid.

Comment: If by "glorified wrapper", you mean "doesn't allocate memory", then sure.